# Why am I getting nonetype when calling a function within a function in Python?

Tags: python, sequence, nonetype, collatz

I'm tying to do a Collatz sequence with python code. I'm supposed to make a function that, given n, calculates the next number in the sequence. I want the next function "write" to print each number within the sequence.

My code so far:

```
def collatz(n):
while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n/2
        return write(n)
    else:
        n = 3*n+1
        return write(n)
def write(n):
    print(n)
    print(collatz(n))

write(6)
```

It gives me the right sequence, which should be 6, 3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1, but also gives me 9 "nones".
I'm new to programming, it should probably be something easy, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: your indent is bad in collatz.  the while should be indented.

Comment: There's no reason for `write` to call `collatz`. While such mutual recursion might make sense for a language without explicit loop constructs, Python *does* have them (and `collatz` is using it) *and* recursion is a terrible way to implement a loop in Python.

Comment: Alright, still trying to figure out recursion, this is one of the first programs I'm making. In the task I have, I have to make another function that writes the numbers from the first one tho, how do I do this without calling collatz in it?

Answer (score 0):

`write()` is a function that executes two `print()` statements, and then implicitly returns `None` (since there are no return statements in the function).

You can simplify the code by using `print()` directly in `collatz()`, and eliminating the mutual recursion:

```py
def collatz(n):
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n//2
            print(n)
        else:
            n = 3*n+1
            print(n)

collatz(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Here this will help you understand. 
#When n becomes 1, the while loop is not executed, 
#collatz does not return write(n)... thus returns None

def collatz(n):
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n/2
            return write(n)
        else:
            n = 3*n+1
            return write(n)

    #return None.... there is no return type, so this is implied

def write(n):
    print(n)
    result = collatz(n)
    if result != None:
        
        print(collatz(n))
```

Comment: Okay! This actually makes sense now! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).